# Generate package.json per Angular project with Nx builder

Tags: angular, build, nrwl-nx

Good morning, I have a Nx project with an Angular app and a NestJS backend for frontend app with some libs for each project.

I’m using the `@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser` build executor for the Angular app, and the specific `@nx/webpack:webpack` for the Backend for frontend server app. In the BFF project I was able to generate the `dist/<bff-app>/` build with the `package.json` for that specific project.

I reviewed the `@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser` but the `generatePackageJson`option is not available. Is any option available to generate the `package.json` and `package-lock.json` in the `dist/<angular-app>/`  or do I need a custom executor?

Comment: You've tagged Nx. Why not use Nx executors and builders from the @nx/angular plugin? They have 1st class support from the team

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I left the default executor when you add to the nx workspace an Angular app. For that reason I didn't update it. If you create with the command `nx create-nx-workspace` and create an Angular application the builder by default is that.

Comment: Apologies, you're correct. I think this is deprecated https://nx.dev/nx-api/angular/executors/package. Other executors are under https://nx.dev/nx-api/angular/executors but couldn't find anything with generatePackageJson

Comment: Nothing to apologize. Thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: To write a custom executor you now need to use `generatePackageJson`from `@nx/js` (the [documentation](https://nx.dev/ci/recipes/other/ci-deployment) is [outdated](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/19310#issuecomment-1744969379)). I have not yet found a better way myself.